# How to get the start Unix timestamp of current hour in MySQL?

Tags: mysql

`UNIX_TIMESTAMP()` function in MySQL gives the unix timestamp of `NOW`.

But I want to get the start unix timestamp of **current hour**.

***is there any way to get it?***

Suppose, the current time is = **`2016-03-07 13:05:23`**

`UNIX_TIMESTAMP() -> 1457334323`

I want to get the unix timestamp of **`2016-03-07 13:00:00`**

**Expected Result:**`1457334000`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `UNIX_TIMESTAMP()` function to do the job done.

```
SELECT (
         UNIX_TIMESTAMP(NOW()) - (MINUTE(NOW()) * 60 + SECOND(NOW())) 
       ) AS startUnixTimestampOfCurrentHour;
```

**Explanation:**

Suppose, `Now()` returns `2016-03-07 13:05:23`.

Now if you look closely then you just need to avoid the `minute` and `second` part. `Minute` and `Second` are expected to have `zero` value.

So if you subtract the `minute`and `second` from `now` then you will reach to the start of the current hour. And then take the `UNIX_TIMESTAMP` of this particular time.

**OR**

`SELECT (UNIX_TIMESTAMP() DIV 3600)*3600 AS startUnixTimestampOfCurrentHour;`

Comment: Thanks got it. And by the way, nice explanation!

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
select UNIX_TIMESTAMP(DATE_FORMAT(NOW(), '%Y-%m-%d %H-00-00'));
```

Comment: Thank you very much. It's another way!

Answer (score 1):

```
select unix_timestamp(date_format(now(), "%Y-%m-%d %H:00:00"));
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use `DATE_FORMAT` to remove minutes/second part:

```
SELECT UNIX_TIMESTAMP(DATE_FORMAT(NOW(), '%Y-%m-%d %H:00:00')) AS result
```

<kbd>**[`SqlFiddleDemo`](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/9eecb7d/48150/0)**</kbd>